# inserting a decimal point to number in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

I've currently got a list of numbers example. 123456 I need to add a three decimal point into the number example. 123.456 I've changed the settings in the options but I have to then type out over 250,000 numbers. is there a formula I can use to automatically do this instead of having to double click or retype the numbers to correct it?

Comment: "I need to add a three decimal point" - do you need to divide it by 1000? or just a decimal point after the third digit (that probably means converting it to text)??

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to format the numbers with a point after three digits from the right, try this:

1. Select the cells or the entire column you want to format, then right click and choose `Format Cells` from the context menu.
2. In the `Format Cells` dialog, under the `Number` tab, select the `Custom` category.
3. In the `Type` textbox type `#.###,` .
4. Click OK.

[image]

**Added:**

If you actually want to change the numeric values you can divide all numbers by 1000 in another column and format those new calculated cells with a decimal point.

Comment: Thanks Atzmon. Worked great for displaying the Decimal Point although the actual number is still seen as a six digit number when copied and pasted. It also changes when currency is applied.

Comment: You can insert a currency symbol in the custom formatting, for example `$ #.###,`. Also, if this solves your problem consider marking my answer as the solution.

Comment: "although the actual number is still seen as a six digit number" - you didn't specified whether you wan't your numbers' value to be changed or only the formatting. Please edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: @MátéJuhász is correct, you should mention clearly if you actually need to change the values (divide by 1000) or just format them with a point.

Comment: "and format those new calculated cells with a decimal point" - why is it necessary if the decimal point is already at the right location after the division?:)

Comment: I've edited my answer above to reflect this as well.

Comment: @MátéJuhász we don't know what formatting the OP is using so we can't be sure he'll see a decimal point if he doesn't explicitly apply this format.

Answer (score 0):

Likely an inefficient use of RAM, but I hope this helps:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)-3)&"."&RIGHT(A1,3))
```

This can be adjusted as needed i.e.

```
=NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)-2)&"."&RIGHT(A1,2))
```

for 2 decimals.